# how installer merges files into executable?

Tags: c#, c++, c, installation, archive

I want to write an installer to copy files to destination directory. And the first thing I need do is merge these files into the installer executable file, then users only need one installer file to install all files.

I googled for a while but didn't find any idea, I think I should archive these files to one file, but what should I do next?

Comment: Why don't you use InnoSetup, InstallShield or some other free setup solution?

Comment: Because the client asks me to write an installer from scratch using c#  even if I suggested there is other solutions like you said.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio with .net you can use the Microsoft's Setup(MSI) Take a look at this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353

or if you want more freedom take a look at Innosetup  http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php
Its free and powerful